# Issue with htaccess after migration to https (website + KeyCDN)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, http-status-code-301

I have an issue that I can't solve, despite many hours of tests and readings in forums.

Yesterday I followed these steps to migrate from http to https :

1. activate the SSL certificate in my hosting panel (a Let's Encrypt certificate included in the shared Apache hosting of my website)
2. update all hard-coded links to HTTPS (canonical urls, js, etc. + each hard-coded KeyCDN link)

   - every page checked with [this tool](https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck) : "no issues found"
3. enable Shared SSL in my KeyCDN panel + force SSL : "Enabled" + update origin URL (http to https)
4. purge the KeyCDN cache

At this step, I had to write the 301 redirection to https in my htacess, to finish the process.

**But : the 301 redirections already coded in my htaccess don't work anymore.**
I had to desactivate my htaccess file since yesterday and that's a huge problem for my SEO.

Error message : "too many redirections"

This is my htaccess :

```
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

##  CANONICAL DOMAIN WITH 301 REWRITE WITHOUT WWW TO WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

##  301 REWRITE WITHOUT .HTML AT THE END OF FILES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

##  OLD SITE WITH 301 REWRITE WITHOUT INDEX.HTML/.PHP IN URLS
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.php  http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

##  301 REWRITE FOR MOVED PAGES
Redirect 301 /old-url-1 http://www.example.com/new-url-1
```

I have tried many pieces of code to make the 301 redirection from http to https, such as :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Nothing works : the website isn't displayed anymore ("too many redirections") even with the previous htaccess, that I had to desactivate.

Could you help me please, to write the good 301 redirection :

- **from http to https,**
- **without www to www,**
- **without .html files extensions**
- **without trailing slash (/) at the end of my directories**

My website is only built with html/css (no CMS).

Thank you in advance because I think there is a redirection conflict somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/normal/secure(/.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "\.(woff)$">
Header unset Vary
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(eot)$">
Header unset Vary
</FilesMatch>
```